Joining two tables & group by name
I am trying to write a SQL query where it collects the User info along with UserPhotos. For some reason my query results in returning same user info with a different photo URL.
select * from User as a JOIN UserPhoto as up ON a.ID=up.UserId

Table User
FirstName | LastName |   DOB    | ID
ABC          YZV         123     1234567 
BCD          XYZ         123     1234568 
XYZ          MCD         124     1234569 
MNO          XYZ         125     1234570

Table UserPhoto
ID |   UserId   | PhotoUrl
01    1234567      https://imageUrl1
02    1234567      https://imageUrl2
03    1234568      https://imageUrla1
04    1234568      https://imageUrlb1

Expected output:
{
  fName: "ABC",
  lName: "YZV", 
  dob: 123, 
  id: 1234567, 
  photos {
   https://imageUrl1,
   https://imageUrl2
  }
}


'For some reason my query results in returning same user info with different photo url.'  is not clear please include data in expected output.

If you get two rows for user 1234567 and two for 1234568, that is the correct and expected output for your query. Your expected output can only be achieved if you do explicit aggregation, which you currently don't do.

@P.Salmon Don't you mean to ask for the actual output?

You could group_concat the photos and then join on them:
SELECT u.*, photos
FROM   users u
JOIN   (SELECT   userid, GROUP_CONCAT(photourl ORDER BY photourl ASC) AS photos
        FROM     userphoto
        GROUP BY userid) up ON u.id = up.userid

